# 500 MB Avi video from CD lagging/glitching when reproduced

Tags: video, compact-disc, video-conversion, avi

I created an extra cd with Nero Burning that contains both audio tracks (I can hear them correctly) and a .avi presentation (pretty big one, 540 MB on a 700 MB cd).

The audio is fine but the problem is that when the video is played from the cd (with whatever media player: Windows Media Player, VLC, etc..) it lags/glitches/stutters.

I'd like the video to be smooth, how should I burn the video to reduce this effect? I mean: what kind of compression/format and why?

Comment: A CD-ROM solution may not be fast enough to display video at high-resolutions/bit-rates.  How are you creating the video now (bit-rate, compression type, resolution, etc.)?  What variations have you tried already?  What's the CD read speed of your optical drive?  Is it just as bad regardless of the drive/computer you try it on?

Comment: How do I find out my cd reader's speed? I've tried avi with Camtasia techsmith codec but that's just bad bad bad and even buffering 2 sec with VLC doesn't solve

Comment: You could probably look up the drive's model with the manufacture to get the specs.  You also managed to avoid all my other questions. :) What video formats, bit-rates, compression, resolutions, etc. have you tried already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As techie007 said in the comments, a cdrom is not fast enough to display video. The best bet for you to enable faster speeds is to lower the resolution and pick a format that has higher compression.